# Babylon.js and Cannon.js camera and wall collisions bugs

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, babylonjs, cannon.js

I've been working through a basic FPS-style project (using a lot of advice I've found from lurking here) and I've run into an issue.

Here's the code, first off- https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#GYZQLK#3

Use the arrow keys to move the camera forward until you hit the wall, and you'll see my problem.

I'm trying to

1. have a natural jumping mechanism, and
2. have collision detection between the camera, ground, walls, etc.

At first I did this just using Babylon's native .checkCollisions, which works very well for camera vs object and camera vs wall collisions. However, I couldn't get this to work properly for jumping. Even following other's tutorials, (http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/12198-camera-jump/) I wasn't getting the results I wanted; on my computer, at least, all of those playground sketches still "hang" at the top of the jump until other arrows are pressed.

So, I switched gears and tried using (individually) Oimo and Cannon for more robust physics. I still can't get Oimo to work, for some reason ( "this.world.worldscale is not a function" ring a bell for anyone? I can't find anything on that) but I've had decent results with Cannon.

In short, I have the jump working, but now the collisions vs the walls are all...funky.

I'm pretty stuck. I don't see how this collision detection is any different than between the ground and the camera, but something is obviously off. I've tried vs other horizontal objects (boxes, spheres) and had the best results setting the camera's physics imposter to a box (which makes turning all jittery).

Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I got some help over at http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/32220-collision-with-walls-using-cannon/ and figured I'd post my results over here as well in case anyone else has run into the same issue.

The short answer is use an animation to control the jump, and let the Babylon physics engine take care of collisions with the camera. Let Cannon do the physics for the other objects.

In order to prevent the camera from hanging at the top of the jump, there's a hidden/undocumented property (cameraname._needMoveForGravity) that you can set = true (which sounds like the opposite of what you'd like, but whatever) that helps.

Just in case anyone else is struggling with this, here's a sketch (with some extra baggage, I trimmed most things out for clarity but not everything)

Press space to jump
http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#NMPK63

Basically I'm using iiceman's example from here-

(thread) http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/12198-camera-jump/

(playground) http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#XN87O

and also Wingnut's suggestion of changing camera._needMoveForGravity = true which successfully keeps the camera from 'hanging' at the top of jumps